# implicit declaration of function 'ipipe_restore_pipeline_head'; did you mean did you mean 'ipipe_test_thread_flag'

Tags: compilation, buildroot, xenomai, adeos

I'm trying to build an embedded OS with buildroot 2020.02 with 2 kernel. My Linux kernel is 4.19.107 and my Xenomai kernel is 3.1. I apply the Adeos patch in order to have the ipipe fetatures : ipipe-core-4.19.106-cip21-arm07 from this site : https://xenomai.org/downloads/ipipe/v4.x/arm/.
The compilation work with an old kernel and an old xenomai version , but with this one I have compilation errors in /include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h and hal.c :

```
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:169:34: error: implicit declaration of function 'ipipe_propagate_irq'; did you mean 'rthal_propagate_irq'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 #define rthal_propagate_irq(irq) ipipe_propagate_irq(irq)
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:524:2: note: in expansion of macro 'rthal_propagate_irq'
  rthal_propagate_irq(irq);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h: In function '__rthal_apc_schedule':
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:168:38: error: implicit declaration of function 'ipipe_schedule_irq'; did you mean 'ipipe_disable_irq'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 #define rthal_schedule_irq_root(irq) ipipe_schedule_irq(irq)
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:537:3: note: in expansion of macro 'rthal_schedule_irq_root'
   rthal_schedule_irq_root(rthal_apc_virq);
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h: In function 'rthal_apc_schedule':
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:118:41: error: implicit declaration of function 'ipipe_test_and_stall_pipeline_head'; did you mean 'ipipe_test_and_stall_head'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 #define rthal_local_irq_save(x)  ((x) = ipipe_test_and_stall_pipeline_head() & 1)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:118:41: note: in definition of macro 'rthal_local_irq_save'
 #define rthal_local_irq_save(x)  ((x) = ipipe_test_and_stall_pipeline_head() & 1)
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:119:36: error: implicit declaration of function 'ipipe_restore_pipeline_head'; did you mean 'ipipe_restore_head'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
 #define rthal_local_irq_restore(x) ipipe_restore_pipeline_head(x)
                                    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:546:2: note: in expansion of macro 'rthal_local_irq_restore'
  rthal_local_irq_restore(flags);
  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:203:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'ipipe_stall_pipeline_from'; did you mean 'ipipe_stall_head'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   ipipe_stall_pipeline_from(ipipe_root_domain); \
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/system.h:159:3: note: in expansion of macro 'rthal_emergency_console'
   rthal_emergency_console();
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
./include/asm-generic/xenomai/hal.h:204:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'ipipe_set_printk_sync'; did you mean 'ipipe_set_hooks'? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   ipipe_set_printk_sync(ipipe_current_domain); \
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I search in the ipipe.h file but unfortunately none of those methods are defined here and I don't find the equivalent.

Does anyone knows if there is an issue ?

Foundly